# in java code using savedInstanceState to save a reusable value

Tags: java, android

I am developing an android app and want to save a rand2(Double type) value using savedInstanceState so that i can use rand2 value whenever app is reopened but while retrieving rand2 value it always comes NULL, Either the value is not saving or value is not retrieving . Why it is happening and what should i do to save rand2 value so that i can reuse it when the app is reopened?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    double rand2;
    private boolean started = false;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    public Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            double rand1 = Math.random() * 5;

            rand2 = rand2 + rand1 * 0.04;

            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

            String message1 = "" + df.format(rand1);

            DecimalFormat dff = new DecimalFormat("000000.00");

            String message2 = "" + dff.format(rand2);

            displayRate(message1);

            displaySatoshi(message2);


            if (started) {
                start(started);
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // recovering the instance state
        // Restore UI state from the savedInstanceState.
        // This bundle has also been passed to onCreate.
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            rand2 = savedInstanceState.getDouble("abc");
        } else {
            rand2 = 0.00;
        }


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        // Find the View that shows the numbers category
        TextView numbers = (TextView) findViewById(withdraw);
        // Set a click listener on that View
        numbers.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            // The code in this method will be executed when the numbers View is clicked on.
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent numbersIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Withdraw.class);
                startActivity(numbersIntent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        savedInstanceState.putDouble("abc", rand2);


        // call superclass to save any view hierarchy
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    }

    public void Start(View v) {


        ToggleButton starStopTogglrButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.start_stop);
        boolean hasStartStop = starStopTogglrButton.isChecked();

        if (hasStartStop) {

            start(hasStartStop);

        } else {
            stop(hasStartStop);
        }


    }

    public void stop(Boolean hasStartStop) {


        //Checking start or stop
        started = hasStartStop;
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
    }

    public void start(Boolean hasStartStop) {
        started = hasStartStop;
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
    }


    private void displayRate(String message1) {
        TextView orderSummaryTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rate);

        orderSummaryTextView.setText(message1);
    }

    private void displaySatoshi(String message2) {
        TextView orderSummaryView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.satoshis);

        orderSummaryView.setText(message2);


    }


}
```

Comment: where are you retieving rand2 and it is null? which is not possible for primitive double

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onSaveInstanceState` is called when the app is closed, but onCreate is only called when the app is booted after it's been finished. Remember the acitvity lifecycle:

[image: enter link description here]

So since `onSaveInstanceState` is called at closing and onCreate only is called when the activity is (re)created, it is null because it isn't added at that time.

You're looking for `onRestoreInstanceState`. Override that method and grab the variable and assign it from there.

Remember that using the savedInstanceState **does not save the data if the activity is completely destroyed**. For persistent data storage, use sharedprefs, files or SQL